# UnsatisfiedLinkError in java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

Following error I got in my application. I can't understand what is it and what is the solution ? Please guide me

```
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no otfxjni in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.FeatureExtractionLibrary.<clinit>(FeatureExtractionLibrary.java:16)
        at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.FeatureExtractor.<clinit>(FeatureExtractor.java:8)
        at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPFeatureExtractionFactoryImpl$FeatureExtractionImpl.<init>(DPFPFeatureExtractionFactoryImpl.java:32)
        at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPFeatureExtractionFactoryImpl.createFeatureExtraction(DPFPFeatureExtractionFactoryImpl.java:19)
        at VarifyServer.extractFeatures(VarifyServer.java:121)
        at VarifyServer.callClient(VarifyServer.java:71)
        at Bean.callServer(Bean.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:131)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:88)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:77)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:743)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:368)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:447)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:752)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:17)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:94)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:54)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:26)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:160)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher$1.service(SessionDispatcher.java:38)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.service(ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.java:19)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.service(EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.java:63)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:55)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:19)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:91)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.FeatureExtractionLibrary` class is using JNI to call out to the `otfxjni` native library (.so or .dll extension).  However that library is not in your library path.

You can manually set this path by adding the `-Djava.library.path=<path to otfxjni file>` argument to your runtime process.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32 this is path in window but i don't know same for linux

Comment: @chetan It varies per system really.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the JVM cannot find the "otfxjni" library. You should check if you actually have that library and that it is in the right place (which will be OS dependent, of course).

EDIT: It will help if you print out the value of the `java.library.path` system variable so you know where it is looking.

Answer (score 0):

The probable cause I see, is that there's no library `otfxjni.dll` (or `otfxjni.so` if you're using linux) in your java library path.

From JavaDoc (of UnsatisfiedLinkError):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine
>   cannot find an appropriate
>   native-language definition of a method
>   declared `native`.

Comment: can i know the path of otfxjni.so ?

Comment: Do a file scan for the library path & place the path to the java lib path.